# Adding a CSS gradient to an image--NOT a background image

Tags: css, gradient

This is a page that uses a carousel (I believe flexslider). The images in this carrousel are NOT background images. I need to add a gradient to the image, going from the bottom up, and from dark to zero opacity, so that I can make the text more legible. Is this possible?

http://hungersolutionsny.magadev.net

Comment: what have you tried? Can you show us some code (not just a link to your site, we want your question to be useful to others in the future as well)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally I am not a big fan of adding markup just for styling. I would go for a pseudo element `:before` or `:after`

The code would look something like this:

HTML

```html
<div class='slideshow-wrapper'>
    <img src='http://www.placekitten.com/800/300'/>
    <h2 class='title'>Some title</h2>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.slideshow-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    float: left;
}
.title {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
}
.slideshow-wrapper:before {
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

And an example: http://jsfiddle.net/VrGeM/

Comment: Hi Peter, I find this interesting but I don't see it working on my own test and even on the link you provided...?

Comment: you probably need to prefix the gradient code. It should work fine in chrome as is. Here is the fiddle with prefixes for the other browsers (defintly IE8 and up): http://jsfiddle.net/VrGeM/1/

Comment: Got this to work by grabbing code from a CSS gradient generator. Thanks! I did read that the pseudo-selector should use a double colon so that it works in IE. I can't test in IE9 because I don't have a copy. Do you know if this works with IE9?

Answer (score 1):

Overlay the image with an absolutely positioned `<div>` that's the same size as the slider.  Give that `<div>` the gradient. Ensure that it's above the images but below the text on top of the images.

It's also pretty easy to create a transparent PNG to use rather than a CSS gradient, which will have the advantage of working in older versions of IE.

Comment: Note that the transparent PNG won’t work in IE 6 without a JavaScript hack.

Comment: True, but I think at this point IE6 is pretty much dead.  IE8, unfortunately, is not.

Comment: IE 6 and 7 is def not a concern. We're not supporting them. Thanks!

Comment: IE8 does support `progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient`, so no real need for the PNG there...

Comment: Does using that cause issues with text readability?  Often those filters make the antialiasing freak out.

Comment: “at this point IE6 is pretty much dead” — depends on your audience, of course, but yes, all the reports point to it being used less and less as time goes on.

Answer (score 1):

The way I ususally do this is via an absolutely-positioned DIV which sits on top of the images and contains the text. Then I give that an opacity like so:

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56);
```

If you want a gradient with opacity, this is a good tool which makes that easy: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to tackle this.  Mainly targeting the `background` CSS property.  If you're looking to target the text that is overlapping the image you could use something simple like this:

```css
body.front #region-content #flexslider-1 ul.slides .views-field-field-banner-statement {
     background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

It doesn't apply a gradient but it does supply a black background with 50% opacity.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't use a gradient in this way... when faced with this problem in the past I have always used an inset box-shadow on a div wrapped around the image. Something like this...

```html
<div class="img-wrap">
  <img src="" />
</div>
```

And then in CSS apply the box-shadow to a pseudo selector...

```css
.img-wrap {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.img-wrap:before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -100px 80px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Check out this CodePen if you want to see it live... http://cdpn.io/qGwLe